# Binding data to each element using HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to implement annotations functionality on my scatter-plot that I have created using d3.js v3. When I click on each data point, the text-box appears where I enter the text. Once the text has been added, it appears as a tool-tip for that particular data point. The way I execute it is:

```
eventGroup.select("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
    })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .on("contextmenu", function() {
        var position = d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
        d3.select("#context-menu")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 220) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px")
            .style("display", "inline-block")
            .on("click", function() {
                d3.select("#context-menu").style("display", "none");
                d3.select("#annotateBox")
                    .style("position", "absolute")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 220) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px")
                    .style("display", "inline-block");
            });
    });
```

And in HTML file I define `addAnnotation` button and the `textarea` where I will add the text:

```
<ul id="context-menu" class="menu" style="display:none;">
    <li class="addAnnotation"><a href="">Add Annotation</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="annotateBox" style="display:none;">
   <div class="annotateInput" style="display:table-caption">
        <textarea rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="100" style="color:black" ng-model="vm.annotateText" autofocus></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="vm.removeButton()">Done</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do next is, the text added in the text-area popped when clicked on a data point, I want that text to be bound to that particular data point and not all. Is there a way to assign the text-area to the event where it was called and not be common to all. Currently, whatever text I add as a part of one data point is displayed in rest of the data points too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to set those values:

1. Changing the datum;
2. Using local variables (v4 only, not your case).

Changing the datum is the most common, idiomatic D3 way to do what you want. Also, as local variables won't work in v3, this is the solution you should use:

#### Solution 1: Changing the datum

This is probably the most easy and documented way. After all, D3 (or DDD) means *Data-Driven Documents*.

Doing that is very ease: just set any property you want using the first argument in the event listener, traditionally called `d` (for "datum"):

```
selection.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
//first argument here ---------------^
```

For instance, a property named `textArea`:

```
d3.select("textarea").node().value = d.textArea || "";
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    d.textArea = d3.select("textarea").node().value;
});
```

Pay attention to this: for this solution to work, your `datum` has to be an **object**.

Here is a very basic example, loosely based on your code. Right-click each circle, type something and click "done". Do the same in another circle, and then right-click again the previous circle: you'll see that the circles keep the data.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var data = d3.range(5).map(function(d) {
  return {
    name: "foo"
  }
});
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 50 * i
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i){
    return color(i);
  });
circles.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  d3.select("#annotateBox")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 20) + "px")
    .style("display", "inline-block");
  d3.select("textarea").node().value = d.textArea || "";
  d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    d.textArea = d3.select("textarea").node().value;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="annotateBox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="annotateInput" style="display:table-caption">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="100" style="color:black" autofocus></textarea>
    <button type="button">Done</button>
  </div>
</div>
<svg></svg>
```

Since you're using D3 v3 the next solution won't work for you right now (changing for v4 depends on the code you have, it can be very easy or it can be a nightmare). However, describing how local variables work is interesting, because the variable is bound to the DOM element, not changing your data structure:

#### Solution 2: local variables

[Local variables](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local-variables) were introduced in D3 v4 and are way less common. Basically, you need to define the local...

```
var local = d3.local();
```

... and set the values inside the event listener:

```
var thisCircle = this;
d3.select("textarea").node().value = local.get(thisCircle) || "";
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    local.set(thisCircle, d3.select("textarea").node().value);
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var local = d3.local();
var data = d3.range(5).map(function(d) {
  return {
    name: "foo"
  }
});
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(_, i) {
    return 50 + 50 * i
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i);
  });
circles.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
  var thisCircle = this;
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  d3.select("#annotateBox")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 20) + "px")
    .style("display", "inline-block");
  d3.select("textarea").node().value = local.get(thisCircle) || "";
  d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    local.set(thisCircle, d3.select("textarea").node().value);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="annotateBox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="annotateInput" style="display:table-caption">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="100" style="color:black" autofocus></textarea>
    <button type="button">Done</button>
  </div>
</div>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing both the solutions. I am trying to implement the first solution on mine but for some reason it won't read  d3.select("textarea").node().value = d.textArea || "";
  d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    d.textArea = d3.select("textarea").node().value;
  });
But I am trying to debug it, I am sure there's some minor error.